# No internet connection, either ethernet or wifi, after updates Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: internet, ethernet, wired

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 since June 2022, so new-ish to this. I am not a programmer, nor do I customize the OS in anyway, I just enjoy using opensource everything. I have a vague understanding of using the terminal back from checking school email via squirrel in 1999, but I obviously pretty much 100% use the gui. I bought a laptop from Lenovo with Ubuntu pre-installed. It currently shows using 20.04.6.

Sometime in the last week, after installing updates, I believe, my computer is not connecting to the internet.

I know it is not a problem with the service or router, as other devices are all connecting normally. There is a question mark over the network connection icon in the systray, when I attempt to connect to any wifi or wired connection.

First, I noticed the wifi not connecting. I went to the store and bought an ethernet cable and usb adapter. Plugged these in. Everything worked fine, instantly. I used the internet via the wired connection for a whole day. I shut down the computer.

When I booted up the following day, same problem: there was now a question mark over the wired connection icon in the top right.

Seems to me this is proof that the issue is somewhere in the software.

When I investigate the wifi/wired settings, everything appears "connected."

Somewhere on the internet, I saw the advice to disable IPv6. And put in a manual DNS as 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1. These appeared to have no effect. I followed online directions to restore the wired profile to defaults. No effect. `sudo service network-manager status` shows Network Manager to be running, it seems. `nmcli device` shows `p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3 wifi-p2p disconnected --`, but the internet does not seem to see this as a problem?

Any simple fixes/advice? if not, I think I am ready to try to bring it to a repair place as it is still under warranty.

Comment: Run this code to auto install required drivers in Ubuntu: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: I don't think it's a driver, since the ethernet cord worked just fine for one whole day.